# Insert Table data and Total into database

Tags: javascript, node.js, pouchdb

i want to add a Expense and investment management in my application 
here is the sample image

[image]

here is my html code

```js
function day(){

var table = document.getElementById('customers');
var sumVal=0;
var sumexp=0;
for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
   Description = table.rows[i].cells[0].firstChild.value,
   Investment = table.rows[i].cells[1].firstChild.value,
   Expenses = table.rows[i].cells[2].firstChild.value,
   sumVal = sumVal +parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[1].firstChild.value);
   sumexp = sumexp +parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[2].firstChild.value);
  
console.log(Description);
console.log(Investment);
console.log(Expenses);
console.log(sumVal);
console.log(sumexp);

}

  
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
input {
  border: none;
}
div{
width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>                       
    <table id="customers">
        <tbody id="mytbody">
            <tr>                                  
                <th>Descritption</th> 
                <th>Investment</th>
                <th>Expenses</th>                                                                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="yourname" /> </td> 
                <td><input type="number" name="yourname" /></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="yourname" /></td>                                   
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="yourname" /> </td> 
                <td><input type="number" name="yourname" /></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="yourname" /></td>                                   
            </tr>
              
        </tbody>
    </table> 
  <input type="button" id="save" value ="save" name="save" onclick="day()">
  
</div>
```

My question is

1. i got all the table values in js now how to insert the values to database
2. on calculating total if there is no number in any cell  is total is returned is `NAN` how to handle this to calculate the all values even if the some cells are empty

i am doing this application on `Electron` js and `PouchDB`
Can any one help me the code in `node js` or `Javascript`

Comment: What have you tried, what did not work? There is not a line Javascript in your code. Just the HTML and some CSS (which is not needed for the question asked). PouchDB and Node.js are not that trivial, so I suppose you have more code already.

Comment: added the js  can you help to me to insert to databse

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but all you did is retrieving the Values from the Table. There is still not enough code for a practical answer. Stackoverflow is not meant to write the code for you - it's meant to help you with defined problems. So what you should do:

1. Think about how you want to store the Data in a document based NoSQL-DB. Because that's what PouchDB is. You have to think about a data structure first. Maybe think about if a simple key-value based local storage would suit your need better.

   that could be something like

   ```
    "_id": "a5dffd2f-5c4f-46a4-abdc-2f1f3569d2cf",
    "_rev": "3-8a1a6dc9ac78b1e388c4b2051e298691",
    "user": "user_1",
    "Date": "1621654503"
    "Data": [{
        "Descritption": "his description",
        "Investment": "20",
        "Expenses": "13"
        },
        "Descritption": "his description 2",
        "Investment": "30",
        "Expenses": "14"
        }]
   ```

   assuming there is more then one line per person
2. Put your `Data`in an array of objects, and the rest in variables.
3. write it to your PouchDB

   ```
    const PouchDB = require('pouchdb-browser');
    let db = new PouchDB('myDB', {adapter: 'idb'});

    db.post({
        Descritption: yourDescritption,
        user: yourUser,
        date: yourDate, 
        Data: yourArrayofObjects,
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
   ```
4. you still have to think about retrieving or updating your data.